# Bootstrap dropdown-menu items wraps

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, word-wrap

My drop-down list breaks items with long text:

[image: Item wraps]

I need it to be in one line, with text and icon pulled left, and label pulled righ. Here is HTML code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a class="clearfix" href="/">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i>
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ticket issues&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
      <span class="label label-warning pull-right">5</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please help.

Comment: No problem here with your code: http://www.bootply.com/mchlN4ej1b must be caused by something else in your CSS

Comment: OK, so the issue occures only when dropdown is inside navigation bar: http://www.bootply.com/HgzrQet5QQ - I track it to .dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

Answer (score 4):

Even if the question is quite old I want to answer since I had a similar experience.
You need to include the following in your css to override the white-space dropdown-items property:

```
.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item{
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

Using this property the text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a br tag is encountered.

Comment: or bootstrap class `text-nowrap` on the item or menu, probably

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your css;

```
.wrapOptions {
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 700px;
}
```